# How should I selectively apply 'transition:' property in one style?

Tags: css

I have some `<li>` tags in an `<ul>`. On hover, `<a>` tags in `<li>` change their background; and I added `transition` property in `li a` style in CSS to give some sort of animation effect.

I also want to change their font size along the window width so I added some media query with `@media all and ...`. The problem is that the transition delay is applied to font size changes.

Here are my codes.

HTML(paste any place in `<body>`):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li a{
    padding: .4em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    transition: .4s;
}

li a:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}

//...

@media all and (min-width:1px){
    ul{font-size: .8em;}
}

@media all and (min-width:480px){
    ul{font-size: 1.2em;}
}
```

I tried in two ways:

1) writing `transition: .4s` in `li a:hover{...}`. In this case the font size changes immediately but transition does not work when cursor leaves the list element.

2) writing `transition: 0` in `ul {...}` in media query. This makes no changes.

What do I have to do in this case?

Edited: I'm sorry but I cannot upload the full code because the codes are fragmented to all components in an Angular2 project. Hope these codes are enough.

Comment: Please create a working example - so we can fix it without scratching head too many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which properties the transition should use

```
transition: background-color 1s;
```

Stack snippet

```css
li a{
    padding: .4em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

li a:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}

@media all and (min-width:1px){
    ul{font-size: .8em;}
}

@media all and (min-width:480px){
    ul{font-size: 1.2em;}
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks man think i've got to check `transition` property more a bit.